# huge shadow appear in UIViewController

Tags: ios

I use [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) for Stack Controller.

But I got a huge shadow on centerViewController following the figure

I have a subclasses JASidePanels (call 'StackController') UIViewController in Storyboard and create center and left Controller and setViewController in StackController with this code

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftViewController"]];
    [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"]];
}
```

[image]

Thanks for Advance.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: I'm edited question detail. sorry for that.

Comment: i think that your mainView background color is clear color, and the the left view is red color.
try to set the mainView.BackgroundColor to whiteColor or what ever you want.

Comment: No, mainView (centerView as you mean?) have "Red" backgroundColor and leftView have "Green" backgroundColor (I doesn't show it.)

Comment: You probably forgot to set your subclass on your controller (through Interface Builder) and kept the `JASidePanelController`.

Answer (score 1):

Search for method
 - (void)styleContainer:(UIView *)container animate:(BOOL)animate duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
You can comment method body to remove shadow.